# Besides Sudan, have any other foreign countries argued before the Supreme Court of the United States?

Tags: us-supreme-court

This term the Supreme Court ruled in the case [Republic of Sudan v. Harrison](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/18pdf/16-1094_3d94.pdf), in which a foreign country, namely Sudan, appeared before the Court to argue its case. Has this ever happened before?

Answer (score 1):

Some examples:

- [*Rubin v. Islamic Republic of Iran*, 583 US ___ (2018)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/583/16-534/).
- [*Republic of Austria v. Altman,* 541 U.S. 677 (2004)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/541/677/)
- [*Argentine Rep. v. Amerada Hess*, 488 U.S. 428 (1989)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/488/428/)

Note that the [Foreign Sovereign Immunities Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Sovereign_Immunities_Act) precludes a foreign country from being sued except under a narrow set of circumstances, so the range of civil cases will be limited.  In fact, in *Rubin v. Iran*, *Austria v. Altman*, and *Argentina v. Amerada Hess*, the main question was whether the FSIA was applicable and whether foreign countries could be sued under any other laws.  The *Sudan v. Harrison* case also touched on whether the conditions of the FSIA had been satsfied.

This answer is community wiki, so people are welcome to add more cases.